# vstest.console.exe gets stuck after first test when executed from TFS Build

Tags: tfs, msbuild-task, vstest.console.exe, microsoft-cpp-unit-test

I have my build definition for my project set up on TFS. I intend to add Task to Run C++ Unit Tests and run them after each build.

I tried and added the task. When the Tests ran on TFSBuild the first test crashed with unhandled c++ exception and did not moved to next test. It hung there itself.

So I tried to run the test manually using command line(cmd). I ran the vstest.console.exe command and executed all tests and they ran fine when ran from cmd on the Build Agent. I also tried running them on Visual Studio and they ran fine on the Build Agent.

I am not sure what is going wrong with the TFS.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution but not the root cause of the issue.
The issue is solved by using an interactive tfs agent.